# Store firebase .json in javascript variable

Tags: jquery, json, firebase, getjson

I'd like to retrieve the .json data of a specific firebase location, and store it in a global variable in my javascript code.

I don't need it to be asynchronous (which I don't fully understand) - I just want to get the .json data ONCE and move on.

I'd like to use the resulting .json data (Object) elsewhere in my code multiple times, that's why I'd like to put it in a global variable.

I'd imagine the jQuery getJSON would help - but I'm confused how to use a callback to set my global variable outside of the function.

Any help out there?

Comment: you should show some research that you have done, what have you tried already? then people can help review your code and suggest improvements to the code or your approach

Answer (score 2):

This does the trick for me... 
Is there something more modern / appropriate to use these days?

```js
function httpGet(theUrl) {
  var xmlHttp = null;

  xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, false);
  xmlHttp.send(null);
  return xmlHttp.responseText;
}


var url = 'https://tuffleague.firebaseio.com/details/teams.json';
var teams = JSON.parse(httpGet(url));

$("#result").text(teams.CAVALRY.division);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.1.1/firebase.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: This is the first time I see a runnable code snippet that uses Firebase. They always used to throw "cross domain" errors, but your doesn't. Nice!